# Can I delete Ultimate Chicken Horse without losing all my progress?

Tags: xbox-one, ultimate-chicken-horse

Can I delete Ultimate Chicken Horse without losing all of my progress?
Sometimes when I click on an online match my game freezes and crashes. I thought deleting it would work. I play on Xbox One.

Comment: If you figured out a solution, you can post it as an answer to help others who may have the same question

Answer (score 3):

## Yes you can.

You safely delete any and all of your games and reinstall them tomorrow, next month, or 3 decades from now (as long as servers are still up) and keep all of your saved data from that game.

This works because your games are all backed up to your account on Microsoft's Xbox servers.

## You can also delete your saved data!

To do this you'll want to go to *My games & apps*, go over to the app you want to remove, press the *Menu* button on your controller, scroll to *Manage game & add-ons*, then to the *Saved Data* box, and then delete it.

Comment: Also to note, UCH has a cheatcode that unlocks everything right away. So If you lost your fully unlocked game, going back to everything unlocked is simple and easy. https://ultimate-chicken-horse.fandom.com/wiki/Unlockables But you would lose all stats, if that is what you want to keep.